# Running node.js with arguments in StrongLoop

Tags: node.js, strongloop

When I run:

```
slc start
```

My project is executed correctly because of the parameters found in package.json

```
...
"main": "node --use_strict -harmony server.js"
...
```

Already StrongLoop Arc can not start my project because it does not have parameters that enable ES6. So how can I configure StrongLoop Arc to pass the correct parameters for Node.js?

```
node -v
v5.4.0
```